# Accessing struct members by a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a multi-instance dialog, whose HWND and DC are contained in a vector of structs. Before I call `CreateWindowEx()`, I allocate memory for a new instance of the struct and pass its pointer to WndProc (with `lpParam`).

Inside the WndProc I have the following code:

```
HexParams Hex;
HexParams *pHex;
if (uMsg == WM_NCCREATE) {
    SetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR) ((CREATESTRUCT *)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
    return TRUE;
} else {
    LONG_PTR lpUserData = GetWindowLongPtr(hDlg, GWLP_USERDATA);
    if (lpUserData) {
        pHex = (HexParams *)lpUserData;
        Hex = *pHex;
    } else
        return DefWindowProc(hDlg, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Then throughout the whole WndProc I'm constantly using `Hex.Member` to acces its memebrs, read from them and write to them (if was left from when it was a single instance and the struct was global). So when I was adding multi-instance support, I hoped that simply dereferencing the pointer would give me the struct memebrs from that vector.

However, the following examples do different things:

```
Hex.DC = GetDC(hDlg);
pHex->DC = GetDC(hDlg);
```

Despite of doing `Hex = *pHex;` before it. `pHex->DC` writes to my vector element, but `Hex.DC` writes to somewhere I can't figure out. Is there a way to preserve `Hex.Member` usage in the code, or I'll have to convert them all to `pHex->Member`?

I may be "missing the point of pointers", but I can't get how to properly use them here.

Comment: `Hex` is a **copy** of `*pHex`. **Pointers are not references!**

Answer (score 2):

`Hex` is a variable defined in that function.  Writing `Hex.DC` will refer to 4 bytes within that structure, on the stack of this function call.

`pHex` points somewhere determined by the caller.  `Hex = *pHex;` will copy the contents of the arriving structure to your local structure.  They are different blocks of memory.

Draw a picture of the stack, block out the activation frame of a call, fill in Hex there.  Draw other blocks where memory is allocated (global, dynamic, earlier calls) and draw arrows to them to indicate pointers.

Comment: So is it possible to access the initial structure when using `.` somehow?

Comment: I don't follow.  If you *have* the original struct instance, then use `.` to get a field from it.

Comment: The dialog Proc doesn't know which vector element it must access for a given dialog instance. So I pass it a pointer to the proper vector element, that is a struct instance corresponding to the dialog copy, giving it variables to use. Anyways, I've already replaced all dots with arrows in my code.

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you were asking.  Given that the struct instance is passed in now, can you avoid editing all the code?  Yes, if you used C++ "as a better C".  You could do what you originally showed, binfing a reference rather than copying the contents.

Comment: Can you post another answer explaining that method?